# Should a married couple with no kids, from outside the EU, approach the UK border control desk separately or together?

Tags: air-travel

The UK Gov says all families should move together but I don't understand if they refer to a family with kids or a married couple without kids is consider a family and should go to the border control together?

Answer (score 4):

The gov.uk website says

> You must ... move through passport control together if you’re in a family

https://www.gov.uk/uk-border-control/at-border-control

and

> To avoid delays, when you arrive at UK passport control, please: 
>   * stay together when travelling as a family

https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/coming-to-the-uk/faster-travel-through-the-uk-border

They don't define what they mean by 'a family'.

I suggest that you approach the desk together. If this is wrong then the worst that will happen is that the passport control officers will ask you to go through one at a time instead.

Comment: I find it extremely unlikely that the definition of "family" could possibly exclude a married couple.  Your mentioning the worst case scenario should however go a long way to reassure skeptical or worry-prone readers, so +1 from me (also for finding an official source!).

Comment: Hi and thank your for your answer. We, by all means consider ourselves a family but as it is not clear the definition of a family we wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

From comments:

> A married couple without kids is still a family.